# ConcurrencyCheck not working EFCore1.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

> EF generated query as under,
>
> P1 and P4, EF is picking us the same latest value instead of earlier stored value to compare with.

```
UPDATE [XYZ] SET [c] = @p0, [time] = @p1
WHERE [a] = @p2 AND [b] = @p3 AND [time] = @p4;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

',N'@p2 varchar(10),@p3 int,@p0 varchar(8000),@p1 datetime,@p4 datetime',
@p2='1234',
@p3=55,
@p0='Test Update',
@p1='2017-11-29 18:25:18.010',
@p4='2017-11-29 18:25:18.010'


----------------------------

public partial class xyz
{
    public string a{ get; set; }
    public int b{ get; set; }
    public string c{ get; set; }
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public DateTime time{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You should to use Timestamp attribute and byte[] data type for your property

Comment: Nope, even Timestamp attribute and byte[] giving the same in EF1.0 core. '@p1' and '@p4' are getting the same value hence update is failing